# Keep google analytics tracking id confidential Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, google-analytics

My question is within Google Analytics how do i keep the ga_tracking_id out of the source code ?
I tried to achieve this through an environment variable but the value of the key is in the source for everybody to see. Here is the relevant code.

production.rb

```
config.ga_tracking_id = ENV['GA_TRACKING_ID']
```

application.html.erb

```
<%# Google Analytics (only in production environments) %>
    <% if Rails.env.production? %>
        <script>
          (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
          (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
          m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
          })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

          ga('create', '<%= Rails.configuration.ga_tracking_id %>', 'auto');
          ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
    <% end %>
```

Then i set the key configuration at heroku

```
heroku config:set GA_TRACKING_ID=UA-xxxxxxxx-2
```

Now the google analytics is working but the tracking id is still in the source. Why is the keys value in the source ? and how can i keep it confidential ?

I am still quite new to application development of any kind, i have been teaching myself through online resources for about 8 months, mainly RoR!
Any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: It's in the source because the JS needs access to it to send back to Google's server to identify your requests. Why do you want to hide it?

Comment: Somebody take that code and add it to their own site(s) and completely Mess up my site's analytics data? 
The motivation might be just that, to mess up my analytics data, or an attempt to get me and others looking at my data to visit their sites (for spam or other malicious purposes, like malware).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to hide Google Analytics tracking ID.
Google requires it in plain text, so even if it was crypted in some way, any request made to google analytics, easily viewable with chrome dev tools, will contain the GA_TRACKING_ID in plain text.

Comment: I may have found a solution here https://blog.kissmetrics.com/protect-analytics-from-hacking/

Comment: UPDATE: I have improved security through filtering my hostname with the following regular expression ( ^(www\.)?myDomain\.com$ ) removed ga js from application.html.erb and implemented a new file within assets/javascripts/google_analytics.js.coffee . See below

Comment: This code is split into sections you will have to put it back together.

Comment: I can't seem to get the script in this comment field so you will have to go see the source. Its well written and easy to understand and its compatible with turbolinks. Go to http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/google_analytics.html

Comment: Last and closing comment, if you use ga in rails4 with turbolinks go checkout the above links. I can now track every page change in real time and if you check my source it appears that the app doesn't have any analytics . It still can be found but its not easy, you can go take a look at the app if your keen and see if you can find the tracking key. Go to https://thawing-brushlands-6780.herokuapp.com